# Data structure for irregular grid

Tags: data-structures, unity-game-engine, grid, kdtree, sector

Im wondering what is the best data structure for grid containing different sized rectangles/squares as game map sectors. I need to acces object within that grid by simple xyz coordinates.

[image]
searched for KdTrees, but they seem to find nearest object, I found also segment trees/interval trees but there is little info about them 
Cheers.

Comment: Start simple: an array of rects will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an octree. That is, you can start with a rectangular parallelepiped that contains the entire region ((0, 0, 0), (x, y, z))(it is a root of the tree). At the next step, split it into 8 rectangular parallelepipeds(((0, 0, 0), (x / 2, y / 2, z / 2)), ((0, 0, z / 2), (x / 2, y / 2, z)) and so on). These 8 rectangular parallelepipeds are children of the root. Keep building the tree recursively for each of them. When a rectangular parallelepiped is completely inside one region, the recursion should stop(so it becomes a leaf of the tree).

To answer a query, start from the root of the octree and go to a proper child until you reach a leaf.

It is also possible to adapt a k-d tree to solve this problem. The idea is similar to the one described above: split a space into two half-spaces, build a tree for each of them recursively. The base case for recursion is the same too: once the current subspace is inside only one region, the recursion should stop.